# Meaning of "bummed to hear she thought so poorly of it"?

Tags: slang

Kindly forgive me when I left once SE in a radical manner.

My question is, I uploaded a music at a site.

It was Cyndi Lauper's [**Goonies r Good Enough.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxLhytQ67fs&list=FLDUi4OEEh1WnwTT5CYPbE-Q&index=29)

And I got a reply saying,

> Love this song, and was **bummed to hear she thought so poorly of it.**

According to [**an unban dictionary,**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bummed) "bummed" is defined as,

> Feeling knocked onto the butt, or bum, by circumstances. Synonym of down, dejected, sad or disappointed.

So my question is, is the reply trying to say, "She(Cyndi) created the whole music with paying not enough attention to it"?

Thank you in advance(m_m).

Comment: Do not use Urban Dictionary to look up words.  It is full of jokes, slang, and intentionally misleading entries.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you for advice. Now I started speaking with U.S people so deeply, but that is the only clue/source. But I will take your advice anyways. I ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found this part already:

> **bummed** adjective
>
> *US, informal*
>
> : in low spirits : unhappy, depressed, disappointed

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bummed

The part you seem to be missing is:

> *think poorly of (someone or something)*
>
> To have a poor or disdainful opinion about someone; to hold someone or something in low regard or esteem.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thought+poorly+of

---

Putting these together, we see that the commenter was saying:

*I love this song, and I was disappointed to hear that she thought the song was not good*

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!